# How to align all desired output to the left with printf in java

Tags: java, format, printf

I'm using `System.out.printf("%-8d | %-5s | %-15s\n", a, b, c);` to format my output and I'm using `-` to align to the left but I want to put a dot that's also aligned to the left next to the `int` number.
for example :
`1.       | 123   | PICO` .

When I put a dot like `%-8d.` the `int` is aligned to the left but not the dot `1      . | 123   | PICO` , how can I make this happen?

Comment: One of options is to first convert `1.` to String `"1."` and later pass it as argument to `printf` to align it to left.

Comment: Something like `System.out.printf("%-8s | %-5s | %-15s\n", nr+".",  123   , "PICO");`. BTW your problem is caused by fact that `%d` represents integers, not floating point numbers so there is no dot support in that placeholder making used dot *simple character which needs to be printed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as to @Pshemo's comment, the dash alone isn't enough, a straightforward solution is to simpily convert the int into a String variable and concatenate a dot after that variable, then using it in the first field with a dash :

```java
int number = 1;
String a = number + ".";

System.out.printf("%-8s | %-5s | %-15s\n", a, b, c);
```

Output :

```
1.       | 123   | PICO
```